# How to Update Django Database After AWS MediaConvert is Completed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-media-convert

I'm Using Python Boto3 for Start Job on AWS MediaConvert. But I want to update the status of file after completing the MediaConvert Job.

Comment: is your problem solved . if solved. how did you got the status of the job in your code.  what aws services have you used. from which service you go the job notification to your code. can you please share the details brother.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this:

Polling workflow:  for small scale tests, short duration jobs, or occasional workflows, your existing code could poll for job status every XX seconds and when status=Complete, your code could then update the DjangoDB. Note, some jobs could possibly take longer than then 15 minute maximum Lambda runtime, so if you are starting the job via Lambda function then be cognizant of total anticipated job run time. Also be cognizant of concurrent API usage, as polling multiple times per second counts against your API transactions-per-second quotas.

For larger scale, duration or frequency, an Event-trigger workflow is recommended. AWS CloudWatch supports calling a Lambda function based on specified types of log events, so for example if your MediaConvert log group  gets a 'Status:Complete" log message, a CloudWatch Rule could detect and forward that message to spawn a new Lambda function which could parse the log entry and update your database accordingly.

Comment: I also have the similar problem. I want the media convert job change status and other changes in to my local java project. how can i write a listener in my  java project that know when the job status changes.  please suggest any code samples using any aws services